# Input must be of type RowSet (GoAnywhere/SQL JDBC)

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

Input must be of type RowSet (GoAnywhere/JDBC/MSSQL)

This is in relation to GoAnywhere MFT/JDBC (6.1)/MSSQL
Anyway, we have GoAnywhere and currently on a version that isn't forced to use Java >=v11 (currently using latest build of v8. As well, the JDBC we have running for GoAnywhere to use is MSSQL JDBC 6.1 (mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar).

However, anytime we use a later version (>=6.2) we get "Invalid input. Input must be of type RowSet."

We specifically use this for a lot of tasks in GoAnywhere when grabbing data from a SQL table and writing to a CSV. It seems like RowSet is functionally broken in later versions?

Here's a snippet from GoAnywhere log file of reading 67k rows and attempting to write the data to a CSV (which it handily does perfectly fine in current JDBC):

```
3/13/23 7:49:18 AM INFO Executing sub-task 'query'
3/13/23 7:49:18 AM INFO Executing statement
… [Redacted, but just a SELECT statement]
3/13/23 7:49:38 AM INFO Query completed successfully and 67,471 row(s) were affected
3/13/23 7:49:38 AM INFO Finished sub-task 'query'
3/13/23 7:49:38 AM INFO Finished task 'sql 1.0'
3/13/23 7:49:38 AM INFO Executing task 'writeCSV 1.0 (Write Dialer Upload File (CSV))'
3/13/23 7:49:38 AM ERROR [9000 - Write Dialer Upload File (CSV)] Invalid input. Input must be of type RowSet.
```

Not really sure what to do is the newer version(s) of GoAnywhere explicitly use Java v11 and that JDBC is no longer supported for that Java, so kind of stuck between rock and a hard place. And GoAnywhere's support has been a bit lackluster in an attempt to resolve this.

Any help about anything MSSQL/JDBC/GoAnywhere (kinda niche, I know) would be greatful to find a workaround for this so we can upgrade GoAnywhere.

Thanks in advance!

I tried many versions of >MSSQL JBC 6.1 and all failed.

Note: software(s) used and their version(s)...

> SQL: MS SQL 2017 Standard
> GoAnywhere: 7.02 (>=7.1 requires Java v11, thus can't upgrade)
> JDBC: 6.1.0.0 (6.0.8112.200 works OK, but >=6.2.2.0 fails)